# UseEffect with empty dependencies and state values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the code below. The problem is, like the documentation says, if you use an useEffect with an empty array of dependencies, you're stuck with the initial values of the states or variables. What can I do to solve the if in line 7

```
const UserNotification = ({ notificationData, unreadNotifications, setUnreadNotifications }) => {
  const [isOpenNotification, setIsOpenNotification] = useState(false);

  const handleClickOutside = (e) => {
    const parent = document.querySelector('[data-notification]');
    if (!parent.contains(e.target)) {
      if (isOpenNotification && unreadNotifications) {
        setUnreadNotifications((s) => false);
      }
      setIsOpenNotification((s) => false);
    }
  };

  const handleClickReadAll = () => {
    setUnreadNotifications((s) => false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div
      data-notification
    >
      <div className="relative">
        <ClassicButton
          type="custom"
          onClick={() => setIsOpenNotification((s) => !s)}
          className="text-custom-gray-3 rounded-full"
          icon={<Icon path={mdiBell} size={1.2} color={theme.colors['custom-gray-2']} />}
        />
        { unreadNotifications && (
          <div className="absolute border-0 rounded-full w-[7px] h-[7px] bg-red-600 bottom-0 right-0" />
        ) }
      </div>
      {isOpenNotification && (
        <NotificationList
          data={notificationData}
          handleClickReadAll={handleClickReadAll}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default UserNotification;
```

Answer (score 0):

You update the `useEffect` when required

```js
const handleClickOutside = useCallback((e) => {
  const parent = document.querySelector('[data-notification]');
  if (!parent.contains(e.target)) {
    if (isOpenNotification && unreadNotifications) {
      setUnreadNotifications(false);
    }
    setIsOpenNotification(false);
  }
}, [isOpenNotification, unreadNotifications]);


useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
  return () => document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
}, [handleClickOutside]);
```

Comment: That will add another listener every time

Comment: @MauroOjeda nope, because you return the function to remove the event listener. This is called whenever the useEffect needs to re-run, so it cleans up the previous one. Read https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1 for details and more specifically the "**When exactly does React clean up an effect**" section.

Comment: had a similar problem with SocketIo in a context, I'll try and let you know. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use a ref (`openAndUnread`) to hold the boolean value of `isOpenNotification && unreadNotifications`, and update it in another `useEffect` block.

```
const UserNotification = ({ notificationData, unreadNotifications, setUnreadNotifications }) => {
  const [isOpenNotification, setIsOpenNotification] = useState(false);
  const openAndUnread = useRef(false);

  const handleClickReadAll = () => {
    setUnreadNotifications(false);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    openAndUnread.current = isOpenNotification && unreadNotifications;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (e) => {
      const parent = document.querySelector('[data-notification]');
      if (!parent.contains(e.target)) {
        if (openAndUnread.current) {
          setUnreadNotifications(false);  
        }
        
        setIsOpenNotification(false);
      }
    };
  
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
  }, []);
```